# $.ajax requests with CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, cross-domain

I'm having troubles with an AJAX request. I was getting the below error:

> Error: Access is denied

I tried this jQuery AJAX request:

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://testwebsite.com/test',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://testwebsite/test',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Data from Server" + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("You can not send Cross Domain AJAX requests: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Can anyone kindly let me know what I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CORS headers need to be put on the *response* back from the server, not your request. If the CORS headers are not in the response then you should add them server-side. If you are not in control of the server to be able to add these headers, then you cannot make the request from JS. You would need to do it server-side instead.

Comment: Those headers you are sending can actually cause a CORS problem.

Answer (score 0):

As [rory-mccrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) mentioned in a comment, CORS protection is designed so that a website cannot directly access the content of another website (in a browser) unless the website being accessed agrees to it.

It would completely ruin the point of CORS if a site just has to send some headers in order to circumvent the defence

Instead, you will need to use a CORS proxy. It's a server that when given a request like `yourCORSproxy.example.com/http://testwebsite/test` would load the page and return it, but with CORS allowed (like a normal proxy but with CORS enabled).

One of these CORS proxies is https://crossorigin.me, but at the time of writing this it is down. It might be more stable if you simply create your own proxy.

---

tl;dr: `testsite.test` should be sending the headers on its response. You should not be sending the headers on your request.